# Why twig block auto display itself

Tags: php, twig, block

I have two blocks "_block.twig" and "display.twig". In _block.twig I have defined the header, footer, contents and macro. I have extended _block and call header and footer blocks.
But the macro block is auto displaying itself without me calling it.

```
#_block.twig
{% block header%}
...
{% endblock header%}
{% block contents%}
...
{% endblock contents%}
{% block footer%}
...
{% endblock footer%}
```

---

```
#display.twig
{% extends('_block.twig') &}
{% block header parent() %}
...
{% block footer parent() %}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clearly state your question?

Comment: His question is clear enough. You are looking for horizontal re[use](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html)

Comment: @DarkBee i tried using your answer and i get an error "Template "_base.twig" cannot be used as a trait."

Comment: @Airn5475 thanks. I  exetended a file and some of other blocks that i didn't call auto display themselves

Answer (score 2):

When you extend a twigfile you will always get all block from the extended file. You can just overwrite the blocks in the display.twig. 
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html

Maybe you can wrap the blocks in the _block.twig with another block so you can overwrite the block in you display.twig. Or just overwrite the block with an empty block.

Comment: Your solution works, Thanks. But what if i have like 10 more blocks that i don't need to use?